# How do I avoid initializing variables when using recursion?

Tags: c, recursion, graph, initialization

I'm using a recursive function, but I'm initializing a queue that stores values  within the function. I want to avoid initializing the queue every time I use recursion, because then I lose the values that I need to store. Unfortunately the code I was given is structured in such a way that I can't modify the function definition.

```
void function(Graph* graph, int edge_id) {

    Queue * queue = new_queue();

    Edge* temp = graph->vertices[edge_id]->first_edge;

    while(temp!=NULL){
        queue_enqueue(queue, temp->v);
        temp=temp->next_edge;
    }
    queue_print(queue);

    if(temp == NULL){
        function(graph, queue->elements->head->data);
    }
```

Comment: You can't modify the function but you can do anotherone what will be used by this one :) `function_bis(Graph *graphe, int edge_id, Queue* queue);`

Comment: Don't initialize a queue that stores values within the function.  Change the name of the function and add the queue pointer as a parameter.  Create a new function that has the same name as the original function and takes the original parameters.  In there, create the queue and call the old function.  Recompile, rebuild.

Comment: @Harambe don't forget to upvote and validate an answer please ;)

Comment: @kaldoran is there a way to validate a particular answer?

Comment: @Harambe just use the checkmark under the downvote button of the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your queue static, that way it will live on across multiple calls to your function and only be initialised once. There are numerous questions and answers here about what static does.

```
    void function(Graph* graph, int edge_id) {
        static Queue * queue = NULL;
        if (queue == NULL) {
            queue = new_queue();
        }

        Edge* temp = graph->vertices[edge_id]->first_edge;

        while(temp!=NULL){
            queue_enqueue(queue, temp->v);
            temp=temp->next_edge;
        }
        queue_print(queue);

        if(temp == NULL){
            function(graph, queue->elements->head->data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: True enough, but this directly answers the original post, the question of whether there's an architectural problem is a wider issue :-) It's also not a bad thing to know, recursive functions often need something like this.

Comment: Well, any solution that adds constraints to the OP's code ought to be highlighted:)  @kaldoran answer does not use static and so does not introduce the single-thread constraint.

Comment: Tried both solutions, this works the best for me. Thank you!

Comment: Note that if you ever leave a partly full queue around, calling the function a second time won't work happily.  The other solution is preferable!

Comment: @Harambe Curious: how did you determine ["best"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115855/how-do-i-avoid-initializing-variables-when-using-recursion#comment73312234_43115953)?

Answer (score 4):

Just create another function and call it into function :)
Thanks to that 'trick' you do not change the function called `function`

```
void function_b(Graphe *graph, int edge_id, Queue *queue) {

    Edge* temp = graph->vertices[edge_id]->first_edge;

    while(temp!=NULL){
        queue_enqueue(queue, temp->v);
        temp=temp->next_edge;
    }

    queue_print(queue);

    if(temp == NULL){
        function_b(graph, queue->elements->head->data, queue);
    }

}

void function(Graph* graph, int edge_id) {
    Queue * queue = new_queue();
    function_b(graph, edge_id, queue);
}
```

Comment: Yes - that would be what I would do.  Easy and safe.